# Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public"

Tags: metadata, solidity

I am doing a criptoCoin and I am using Solidity and I have the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

For some reason it gives me this error:

> browser/IERC20.sol:6:5: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting
>   to "public".
>       function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

And it's giving this in all of my Functions, I don't know why.
Can anyone please tell me what's is going on ?

I am using Ethereum, Solidity and Metadata to do this, but to be able to do the next step I need my interface to work without any of these error.

Answer (score 2):

**I had to add the "Public" to the Function.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint256 totalSupply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make all those functions public, globally instead of editing each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a static warning you get when you don't describe the function as public explicitly but won't affect the working of contract.If you write a function definition for all it will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add EXternal instead of public

> function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).